# Editing columns and sending data to database from views.py Django

Tags: python, django

my problem is that I can't make query directly in my views.py. I am writing app that allows user to take the test. But problem is that when I send filled form from the test page to my views.py and call `form.save()`, the query is not made in the exact moment, so I can't edit this query in the next lines of code. Is there any way that I could get around this? Some kind of form.send?
Below is my code 
**views.py:**

```
if form is valid:
    form.save()     #i send data to DB
    choiceIndex = Choice.objects.latest('id').id
    choice = Choice.objects.get(pk=choiceIndex)
    choice.user = Users.objects.get(name=username)
    choice.save()   #i want to edit column made earlier
    return redirect("detail", question_id)
```

**models.py:**

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to add user to your newly created object? You'd do this like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.user = Users.objects.get(name=username)
    # or maybe you mean obj.user = request.user here?
    obj.save()
    return redirect("detail", question_id)
```

There is some information regarding this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) in the Django docs.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed! Btw. it's my first "big" project in Django and I forgot that Django has implemented function for Users (request.auth, request.user etc) so I hardcoded that. But next time I will try to use this Django function!